# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel when using client certificate from local machine

Tags: c#, x509certificate, dotnet-httpclient, client-certificates

I am calling an API that requires a client certificate.  With the client certificate installed into the Personal store of `Current User`, the API call is successful.  But when the client certificate is installed into the Personal store of `Local Machine`, the call fails with:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Here is the setup code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;            
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

const StoreName storeName = StoreName.My;
const X509FindType findType = X509FindType.FindByThumbprint;
const string findValue = "9ce5b57fe576b9a0933b426347e74e5583da59dd";

var certCurrentUser = GetCertificate(storeName, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, findType, findValue);
var certLocalMachine = GetCertificate(storeName, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, findType, findValue);
```

Both calls to `GetCertificate()` succeed and the certificates appear to be *identical*.  (They were installed from the same .pfx)

When this call is made with `certCurrentUser`, it succeeds:

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certCurrentUser); 
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://preprod.xconnectcollection.ce.corp.com/odata");
}
```

But when the call is made using `certLocalMachine`, it fails:

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certLocalMachine); 
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://preprod.xconnectcollection.ce.corp.com/odata");
}
```

Error:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

What could be causing the request to fail when using the client certificate from local machine?

Comment: The certificate need to be in both machine and user.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/local-machine-and-current-user-certificate-stores?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng, your suggestion is incorrect.

Comment: @jdweng, First, I don't think that's true.  But, it just so happens that it is installed in both and it still doesn't work when I try to get it from local machine.

Comment: @MarkGood, this is because your web application runs under app pool account which doesn't have permissions to access private keys stored in local machine. Either, use CurrentUser store or explicitly grant your app pool read permissions on private key installed in LocalMachine store.

Comment: @Crypt32 that's interesting and good to know, thank you!  However, my app is a console app, not a web application.  Wouldn't it run as me?  And I can read the certificate from both locations, I just can't seem to use the one in local machine.  :-(

Comment: I just repeated what I read earlier this year that said certificates had to be loaded in both machine and user.  Why not use what is working?  A machine may have many users and not all users should have access to all certificates.

Comment: @jdweng accept it's not working in my case.  ‍♂️  Thank you for commenting though.  Appreciate it!

Comment: @Crypt32, you were on the right track with account permissions.  I just needed to grant permissions to myself to access the private key.  Thank you!

Comment: @jdweng where did you get it? The article you referenced discuss the root certificate of the driver signing certificate. It is very different use case and has different certificate/trust requirements.

Comment: @Crypt32 : Where does it say anything about the driver?  There should be no difference on how a certificate gets stored.

Comment: Look at parent category of the article you referenced. It is under Drivers. And indeed there is a difference, because the article discuss root certificates (which propagate to user stores) while this thread is about personal store which doesn't propagate and is used differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the account running the application has full permissions to the certificate's private key.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The OP has the certificate loaded in both Machine and User.  Unless the OP removed the certificate from the Machine we will never know if certificate will work with only certificate loaded for the user.